# How to change multiple labels that depends on input and executing code generated to string in C#?

Tags: python, c#, string, label, execute

I have no one to ask so I will try here.

Im trying to recreate UI application from python to C# that help our technicians check test log files on multiple servers.

I have lot of labels in UI (using visual studio win forms), that shows technician if the log exist or not on different folders.

for that I need to change specific labels Text property a lot.

Before, in python, I created function that create string of code from different inputs (lists by for loops as program checking servers and folders one by one). And than execute the string variable with "exec" function - simple as that.

for example function that change every label text property to ".........." (something like clear for new search) after clicking on "clear" button

```
...
for serv1 in range(len(self.servers)):
    for i in range(len(self.log_types)):
        clearStringCode = ('self.label_' + str(self.servers[serv1]) + '_' + str(self.log_types[i]) + _v.setText("..........")')
        exec(clearStringCode)
```

Im trying to do this same way in my C# program but there is no function as exec in C# language :(

example: I want to change text of label "labelL1TestStart" and few more from list to "NotFound"

```
        private void folderNotFound(string area, string server, List<string> types)
        {
            foreach (string type in types)
            {
                string labelName = "label" + server + area + type; //creating button name to string
                string toExec = labelName + ".Text = \"Not Found\";"; //creating code to string
                SomeFunctionToExecuteTheString(toExec);
            }
        }
```

My question is - is there some way how to execute string generated in foreach like this? Or what is the proper way to do this.. changing labels based on input variables? Am I missing something? Im not really programmer. Thank you for answer.

Picture from my python application that Im trying to recreate:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netcore-3.1) method, something like this

```cs
private void folderNotFound(string area, string server, List<string> types)
{
   foreach (string type in types)
   {
      string labelName = "label" + server + area + type; //creating button name to string
      var control = this.Controls.Find(labelName, true).FirstOrDefault();
      if (control != null)
      {
          control.Text = "Not Found";
      }
      else
      {
          // Do something else here
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using [`Control.Controls.Find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_Find_System_String_System_Boolean_) to find the control with the specified `.Name` property and then set its `.Text` property directly like so:

```
private void folderNotFound(Control container, string area, string server, List<string> types)
{
    foreach (string type in types)
    {
        string labelName = "label" + server + area + type; 

        var label = container.Controls.Find(labelName, searchAllChildren: true).FirstOrDefault();

        if (label != null)
            label.Text = "\"Not found\"";
    }
}
```

The `Control container` parameter is the form that contains the labels/buttons that you want to adjust the text for. If the `folderNotFound()` method is defined inside the form that contains the label/button, you can omit that parameter and use `this` instead:

```
private void folderNotFound(string area, string server, List<string> types)
{
    foreach (string type in types)
    {
        string labelName = "label" + server + area + type; 

        var label = this.Controls.Find(labelName, searchAllChildren: true).FirstOrDefault();

        if (label != null)
            label.Text = "\"Not found\"";
    }
}
```

This all assumes that you have set the `Name` property of the pertinent labels/buttons in the designer, of course.